# JAR not loading in Grails web app when running on Linux JBOSS server

Tags: java, linux, grails, jboss6.x

I've developed a Grails web application that relies on a JAR file provided by another team in my company, and for some reason when deploying the app to a Linux JBOSS server its getting errors when referencing the classes in that JAR file.

I developed the application on Windows 7, using Grails v2.4.3 and Java v1.7, and the JAR file is stored within the /lib folder. Everything works fine in developer setup (i.e. using run-app).

Also tested the WAR file on a local Windows 7 instance of JBOSS v6.3, and  everything works correctly.

Only when deploying the same WAR file to the Linux JBOSS instance, also running Java v1.7, do I get the reference errors.

Example error:

```
Error initializing the application: No such property: <prop_name> for class: <class_name>
```

In troubleshooting, I even tried purposely leaving out the JAR file from the WAR package, and gave the same errors. Though in that case, obviously, it was in all server instances, not just the Linux one.

So seems clear that the JAR file simply isn't being loaded correctly, I just have no idea why or how to resolve.

Thank you.

Comment: Essentially that was it. Accidentally included another unneccessary JAR file, which had some conflicts. But only presented on Linux ... I'm guessing things loaded in different, or something like that.

Comment: Great, so you're set